# pandas numbering/sequencing for sets of same column values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

In pandas, How to do numbering/sequencing for sets of same column values? For example:

```
Col1 Col2
Andy  1
Chad  1
Bill  1 
Andy  2
Bill  2
Bill  3
Chad  2
```

Bill  4
Since Andy got 2 values, I want to number it 1 and 2 in Column 2. For Bill, I want to number it 1, 2, 3 and 4 and so on.

Comment: I tried:     def func(x):   x=x.append(rannge(len(x))                              df.groupby('Col1').apply(func) and it is super slow on large data sets

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a cumulative count of the names in `Col2`, which would simply be;

```
df['Col2'] = df.groupby('Col1').cumcount()+1
```

A sample;

```
    Col1
0   Andy
1   Chad
2   Bill
3   Andy
4   Bill
5   Bill
6   Chad
7   Bill

df['Col2'] = df.groupby('Col1').cumcount()+1

    Col1  Col2
0   Andy     1
1   Chad     1
2   Bill     1
3   Andy     2
4   Bill     1
5   Bill     2
6   Chad     2
7   Bill     3
```

Comment: Thank you.The problem that I have is that in my data set, the total number of unique names is 16 milion. So, Group by is very slow. Do you have any suuggestions to accelarate the process?